# Content of TinyMCE/RichTextEditor is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, sapui5, rich-text-editor

I have two adjacent `div`s. Text can be edited or pasted directly into the `div` without deleting the `div`.

In plain HTML code it is working fine but when I am trying to put the same HTML code in RichTextEditor, it is not working as expected. Whenever some content is pasted or a key is pressed after selecting all the contents of a `div`, the whole `div` is getting deleted.

I understand that by default all the contents in the editor are editable, so to stop it from getting deleted I have written a workaround code by setting "contenteditable" property of `div`s.

This is the plain HTML code with workaround which is working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/0vfe1k37/

This is the RichTextEditor with workaround-HTML code: https://jsfiddle.net/fyncyteu/. In this when I am pasting any text after selecting all the contents, either the `div` is getting deleted or I am not able to edit the contents anymore.

I troubleshoot this and found that after pasting this `div` element is getting added to the body with the copy of editor's content.

```
<div data-mce-bogus="all" class="mce-offscreen-selection" id="sel-mce_0" style="top: 0px;">
```

If I remove `oRTE.setPlugins([{name:"paste"}]);` then it is working fine and I don't understand why, maybe some pasting behaviors are getting changed. But I need this plugin. Any other workaround?